# How do I read numbers with appscript from a google sheet and want to use the number as formatted on another sheet"

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, format, numbers

I am doing a dependant dropdown list in google sheets using a script.
The source sheet data is read into an array, The destination sheet pulls the dropdown options from the aray.
The numbers from the source sheet are formatted as degrees; 0°, 45°, 90°, 180°.
When the are displayed in the dropdown on the destination sheet the degree symbol is removed and the 0 option doesn't show as an option at all. so I get 45, 90, 180. If I format the destination cell as percent, the the chosen option doesn't match the validation. and I still can't get the 0°.
How can I pass the formatting with the numbers so everything works correctly?

I was thinking I need to do something with `setNumberFormat('##0"°"')`, but I don't know how.

This is how I am creating the data from the array:

```
var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() .getSheetByName(mainWsName) ;
var wsOptions = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() .getSheetByName(optionsWsName) ;
var options = wsOptions.getRange(3, 2,wsOptions.getLastRow()-2, 5).getValues();
var optionsFormat = wsOptions.getRange(3, 2,wsOptions.getLastRow()-2, 5).getNumberFormat()
```

This is how the data is being retrieved from the array:

```
var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(o){ return o[0] === firstLevelColValue && o[1] === val });
var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){ return o[2] });
var cell = ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn) ;
applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
```

This is my first time asking a question here, I hope I have given the information necessary to solve my problem. Let me know if there is additional information needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues) instead of `getValues()`

This will allows you to retrieve the values in exactly the same way as they are displayed in the spreadsheet.